# Tunnel using SOCKS5 proxies

Tags: php, windows, ssh, socks

Good day,

I have to create a tunnel using SOCKS5 proxies (I think) to browse over (https) a final server behind a NAT.
Can't access the final server directly, I have to access it from another PC on the network.
I can't do port forwarding to the PC.

So my idea of the setup would be to chain 2 SOCKS5 proxies this way:

BROWSER <> PUBLIC WEB SERVER (SOCKS5) <> Windows PC (SOCKS5 BEHIND NAT) <> SERVER (BEHIND NAT)

Although, several things are not clear to me:

- How does the public Web Server (SOCKS5 1) forward to the PC (SOCKS5 2) if it's behind a NAT?
  Does the proxy on the PC has to be of the reverse type?
- The public Web Server (SOCKS5 1) is running PHP.
  Can I run a PHP SOCKS5 proxy implementation?
  Should I set up an SSH tunnel instead?
  Should I use Web-Sockets?

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: I think you need to use Serverfault, and not Stackoverflow :)

Comment: @RogerAI thanks for the reference. Although i do need to code to build/setup the proxies.